# Software adjustment of LCD monitor brightness in Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, display, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This is my first post here. I'm at the beginning of the road called Raspberry Pi.

Is there any way of changing the gamma/contrast/brightness of monitor via Raspberry Pi?

My Samsung 960BF doesn't have any hardware adjustment, only a power button.

I tried using `xbacklight` and got error

> "No outputs have backlight property".

`gddccontrol` also didn't work. Error:

```
I/O warning: failed to load external entity "/home/pi/.dccontrol/monitorlist"  
   Document not parsed successfully
   Probing for available monitors"
```

And nothing is happening.

I connected my monitor through DVI-HDMI cable. Maybe this is why it doesn't work?

I'm using Raspberry Pi B+ V1.2 with Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

One tool I have used successfully (not on a pi though), is `xcalib` from the package of the same name. You can use it to change the gamma, eg:

```
xcalib -gc 1.1 -a
```

You can repeat this. To cancel use

```
xcalib -clear
```

Another useful option is making the whole screen reverse-video:

```
 xcalib -invert -a
```

It is intended to work with icc profiles, but I have only used the above commands.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this, but nothing happens, end after executing command: xcalib -b 99 there is an error:    "Warning: Unable to read file ' ' "

Comment: You would need  `-b 99 -a` but I wouldnt do that, the screen will be all white.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. I tried 'xcalib -b 99 -a',   'sudo xcalib -b 99 -a' ,  and 'xcalib -b 10 -a' to make sure my monitor is not set to max brightness already. There is no error and nothing is happening. I'm afraid that I will need to learn i2c and control the monitor by that...

Comment: Perhaps your cable is not passing through the i2c data line. Look in your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or similar log file to see if the display's eeprom was found (look for `EDID`).

Comment: Nothing like that exists in this file. There is only a line telling that Rpi is using default monitor  and : "no device specified for default monitor section". Must I buy a new HDMI-DVI cable, or there is another way?

Comment: This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) article on DVI says pins 6 and 7 carry the DDC (i2c) signal. And for [hdmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) it is 15 and 16. You could use a multimeter to see if your cable passes these signals, or if the pins even exist.

Comment: I used multimeter and it seems to be a voltage on 6 and 7 pin, so there must be a software issue. I checked and my monitor has DDC 2B.

Comment: Also, I tried 'sudo i2cdetect -y 1' and there are no ports detected... very strange.  EDIT: after adding  'device_tree=' to '/boot/config.txt', I managed to detect some ports with i2cdetect. There is 'UU' visible on B 10 and B 30. Despite this, I still can't change anything with xcalib.

Comment: xcalib as I understand it only works within the X server. To chat with the monitor there is `ddccontrol`.

Comment: Now, in Xorg.0.log I can see the monitor device `Allwiner A10/A13 FBDEV` . it seems like i2c is now working, but is busy (UU). After typing `ddccontrol -p` I get an error `pcilib: can't find any working access method`.

Comment: There is also `(...) monitorspcilib: Can't open  /proc/bus/pci` And there is no `pci` folder there as Raspberry doesn't have a pci bus. There is no way of using ddccontrol then?